# Host Laravel on apache tomcat, routes not working properly

Tags: php, laravel, tomcat

I want to host my laravel 5.2 project on apache tomcat server.

I have tried to host my laravel application on tomcat, but my routes are not working, getting 404 not found.

Comment: Check configurations. Check proper path is set or not.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include your route definitions.

Comment: Added tags to attract attention from specific experts.

Answer (score -1):

Please follow following steps:

1. Copy your Laravel Project's root folder to `/var/www/html`, or clone your
   project on this path
2. Run `composer install` (You must have [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) installed already)
3. Copy `.env` file from local environment to you server on project's root directory
4. Run `php artisan key:generate`
5. run `chmod -R /var/www/html/{project_dir}/storage`
6. run `chmod -R /var/www/html/{project_dir}/bootstrap`
7. run `cd /etc/apache2/sites-available`
8. Here you will find `nano 000-default.conf` file. Open it & change `DocumentRoot` options like `DocumentRoot /var/www/html/{project_dir}/public` and save it
9. Next, Find the `apache2.conf` located in `/etc/apache2`
10. Search for following lines in `<Directory />`:

    ```
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all denied
    ```
11. Change it to this:

    ```
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    ```
12. run `sudo a2enmod rewrite`
13. run `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: This is for xampp apache, but i have tomcat 9 server which is separate from xampp.